# How can I see to which Access Point I'm connected?

Tags: networking

There are some access points with the same name of SSID in my office. All of them are setup on RADIUS server, with Authentication Method: WPA2-Enterprise. How to see to which Access Point I'm connected?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise, Windows 7 Home and Windows 7 Professional

Comment: What identifying information are you after, if not the SSID? How are you planning on distinguishing one from the other? For instance, if you have 4 APs, all with the same SSID and all the same model, what specific information do you need to know which is which?

Answer (score 0):

Metageek's InSSIDder tells you a list of available APs and the one you are connected to. Today is a trial ([inSSIDer office](http://www.metageek.net/support/downloads/)), but older versions were completely free.

I use 2.1.6 version. Try some others at [MetaGeek Software Archives](http://www.metageek.net/support/metageek-software-archives/)